# DbContext AutoDetectChangesEnabled set to false detecting changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I'm a bit stumped. From what I've read setting the `DbContext.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false` should disable change tracking requiring one to call `DbContext.DetectChanges` in order to identify changes to be sent to the database.

However, it is clear from my logs below that the changes are being registered by dbContexts change tracker, even with the setting set to false.

Am I missing something?

Entity Framework Version: 5.0.0.0

DbContext class

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Project> Projects {get;set;}
}
```

Controller class

```
private ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext();

public method(){
    Project p = new Project("uniqueName");
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.Projects.Add(p);
    DebugChangeTracker();
    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Projects.First().ProjectName = "a differentName!";
    DebugChangeTracker();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Logging method

```
    private void DebugChangeTracker()
    {
        var path = "C:\\mypath\\";
        path = path + Util.GetMsSinceEpoch().ToString() + "changeTracker.log";

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            var changeTracker = db.ChangeTracker;
            var entries = changeTracker.Entries();
            foreach (var x in entries)
            {

                var name = x.Entity.ToString();
                var state = x.State;

                sw.WriteLine("");
                sw.WriteLine("***Entity Name: " + name +
                             "is in a state of " + state);
                var currentValues = x.CurrentValues;
                sw.WriteLine("***CurrentValues***");
                PrintPropertyValues(currentValues,sw);
                if (state != EntityState.Added)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("***Original Values***");
                    PrintPropertyValues(x.OriginalValues,sw);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

First log

```
***Entity Name: Models.Projectis in a state of Added
***CurrentValues***
ProjectId:0
ProjectName:uniqueName
```

Second Log

```
***Entity Name: Models.Projectis in a state of Modified
***CurrentValues***
ProjectId:1
ProjectName:uniqueName
***Original Values***
ProjectId:1
ProjectName:a differentName!
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false` doesn't disable change tracking. (That's what the `AsNoTracking()` extension method would do.) It just disables the automatic call of `DetectChanges` that would otherwise occur in many `DbContext` API methods.

But `DetectChanges` isn't the only method that participates in change tracking. However, if you don't call it manually at the right places where it is needed the tracked entity states are incomplete or wrong leading to incorrectly saved data.

In your case the state `Added` in the first part of your `method` is expected, even with `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` set to `false` because you only call `db.Projects.Add(p)`. (The line is missing in your code btw, but I guess it's just a copy and paste error.) Calling a method from the `DbContext` API tracks changes correctly and the states in the tracker will be correct if the state was correct before the call to `Add`.

Or in other words: Calling an API method doesn't turn a correct state into a wrong state. But: If `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `false` it also won't turn a wrong state into a correct state which would be the case if `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `true`.

However, in the second part of your `method` you are just changing a POCO property value. After this point the change tracker state is wrong (`Unchanged`) and without a call to `DetectChanges` (manually or - if `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `true` - automatically in `ChangeTracker.Entries` or `SaveChanges`) it will never be adjusted. The effect is that the changed property value is not saved to the database.

In the last section mentioning the state `Unchanged` I'm refering to my own test (and also to what I would expect). I don't know and can't reproduce why you have state `Modified`.

Sorry, if this sounds all a bit confusing. [Arthur Vickers can explain it better.](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/)

I find automatic change detection and the behaviour when disabling it rather difficult to understand and to master and I usually don't touch the default (`AutoDetectChangesEnabled` = `true`) for any tracked changes that are more complex than the simplest things (like bulk adding entities in a loop, etc.).

Comment: I had to read over that a few times but that does help answer my question quite a bit, thanks! Sorry about the copy and paste error; i'll update the question for posterity.

Comment: Unfortunately, "bulk adding entities in a loop," is when you want change tracking disabled.  It is a _massive_ speedup (sample size of 1, tested in my app, but it was the only difference between two runs adding ~3000 rows).

Comment: @EdS.: Bulk adding is one of the "simplest things" I meant where I actually *would* disable automatic change detection.

Comment: Maybe useful link: [`Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)

Comment: How to mock it?

Answer (score 34):

If someone looking for `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` in Entity Framework Core you can find it under `ChangeTracker` insted of `Configuration`

Usage like:

```
context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

//Do something here
context.PriceRecords.Add(newPriceRecord);

context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Searching for this inside Configuration for so many hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

according to Entity [Framework Automatic Detect Changes's Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx)

they said:

> you may get significant **performance improvements** by turning it **off** in `some cases`

look at this example from that article

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; 

        // Make many calls in a loop 
        foreach (var blog in aLotOfBlogs) 
        { 
            context.Blogs.Add(blog); 
        } 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true; 
    }
}
```

This code avoids unnecessary calls to `DetectChanges` that would have occurred while calling the `DbSet.Add` and `SaveChanges` methods.

Comment: If you turn it back on in the finally block, does it automatically do what it would have done if it had been on but quicker?

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a huge performance boost by turning AutoDetectChangesEnabled off.

I was adding thousands of records in a list and turning this off caused the running time to go from hours to a few minutes.