# Turn off EF change tracking for any instance of the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, change-tracking

I have a context to a read-only database for reporting and I am writing lots of code, like this:

```
using (var context = new ReportingContext())
{
    var reportXQuery = context.ReportX.AsNoTracking();

    // Do stuff here with query...
}
```

Is there a way to set the `AsNoTracking` bit so that just `new`ing up the `ReportingContext` above would automatically use `AsNoTracking` instead of needing to remember to explicitly call it every query?

Answer (score 25):

Try changing your context constructor to this:

```
public ReportingContext()
{
this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This will after all not help you, as stated on Arthur's blog, it is usable only in particular scenarios:

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the difference between `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` and `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: Actually after reading the thread in the comment above, seems that my answer will not help you much. I was sure that this configuration setting affects change tracking globally but it seems it does not affect it in a way you want it. Sorry :)

Comment: Setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`...It just disables the automatic call of `DetectChanges` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes

Comment: in EF6 use this code: ```context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;```