# Entity Framework not changing EnityState on Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

I have a working `Update` method , which is simply changing a property value and calls `SaveChanges()` on db context:

```
public void Update(int id, string name)
{
    var entity = context.Entities.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    entity.Name = name;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

this way changes do indeed get applied , however the `EnityState` remains "Unchanged". Any thoughts as to why? I am trying to avoid having to tell EF what's happening explicitly e.g. using `context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`

the problem is I am using the state in the overriden SaveChanges method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

    var objectStateEntries =
        context.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified);
    ...
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

..when debugging, i can see that the state of my entity is `Unchanged`.

Comment: Before calling SaveChanges the state ist MODIFIED
After calling SaveChanges, the state is UNCHANGED

Comment: After that line "entity.Name = name;" state should be Modified, but after that "context.SaveChanges();" it should be Unchanged again.

Comment: @CyrilIselin  it's not . see update.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't disabled the [change tracking of EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925111/turn-off-ef-change-tracking-for-any-instance-of-the-context) or [proxy creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx), then you shouldn't have problem with that update. EF by default tracks automatically changes when you entities meet the requirements you can find in this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx). If you meet those requirements and check later the type of you entity once is returned by `Single` extension method you will see that is a proxy class, not your real class. So, first check if you're meeting all those requirements that EF needs to track your changes automatically, you'll be fine with that code.

**For either of these proxies to be created:**

- A custom data class must be declared with `public` access.
- A custom data class must not be `sealed`
- A custom data class must not be `abstract` .
- A custom data class must have a public or protected constructor that
  does not have parameters. Use a protected constructor without
  parameters if you want the `CreateObject` method to be used to create a
  proxy for the POCO entity. Calling the `CreateObject` method does not
  guarantee the creation of the proxy: the POCO class must follow the
  other requirements that are described in this topic.
- The class cannot implement the `IEntityWithChangeTracker` or
  `IEntityWithRelationships` interfaces because the proxy classes
  implement these interfaces.
- The `ProxyCreationEnabled` option must be set to true.

**For change tracking proxies:**

- Each property that is mapped to a property of an entity type in the
  data model must have non-sealed,
  public, and `virtual`  get and set
  accessors.
- A navigation property that represents the "many" end of a
  relationship must return a type that implements `ICollection`, where T
  is the type of the object at the other end of the relationship.
- If you want the proxy type to be created along with your object, use
  the `CreateObject` method on the `ObjectContext` when creating a new
  object, instead of the new operator.

Comment: i don't fancy changing default configuration / adding extra code, just want to understand why EF doesn't change `EntityState`

Comment: Did you check if your entity meet the requirements that EF needs to create a proxy class? Check the msdn page that I quoted in my answer

Comment: it does, granted `ProxyCreationEnabled=true` is default.

Comment: No, I wasn't referring about that. Your entities should meet some conditions to create the proxy class . please read the msdn page