# How to delete records in a many-to-many association with a hidden intersection table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We have two tables, table1 and table2, defined in SQL, that have a many-to-many relationship.

As is the usual practice, we've implemented this by creating an intersection table, table1_table2, that contains the primary keys of table1 and table2.

And we've created 1-many FKs from table1 to table1_table2 and from table2 to table1_table2.

Then we had EF6 create an EDMX, using import from database.

The model defined two entities, table1s and table2s, with a many-to-many relationship.

That is, there is the POCO class table1 contains an ICollection table2s, and class table2 contains an ICollection table1s.

How do I clear the connection, so that I can delete all the instance of table1?

This:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    dbContext.table1s.RemoveRange(dbContext.table1s);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Throws an exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_table1_table2_table1".
```

I tried nulling out the relationship, first:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    foreach (var table1 in dbContext.table1s)
        table1.table2s = null;

    dbContext.table1s.RemoveRange(dbContext.table1s);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

And I get the same exception.

So I tried removing each table2 record explicitly:

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
    foreach (var table1 in dbContext.table1s)
    {
        foreach (var table2 in table1.table2.ToList()
        {
            table1.table2s.Remove(table2);
        }
    }

    dbContext.table1s.RemoveRange(dbContext.table1s);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

And that seems to work, but it's so tedious that I have a hard time believing that that is the way that I'm supposed to be doing this.

Ideas?

Comment: Could have saved yourself a lot of head-scratching by not using EF :)

Comment: When we get the current refactoring done, we'll be able to swap out EF with Dapper or NHibernate on a class-by-class basis. But with the constant influx of urgent-but-not-important tasks, that's going to be a long slog.

Comment: It has its places, but a lot of the time you don't need it. Way more transparent when you use something like dapper as long as it's not super complex graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EF

Well, that's just the way to do it with EF.

It is not exactly too much code and can even be generalized if that is required.

If the problem is **performance** then it may be partially dealt with by

1. [disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925111/turn-off-ef-change-tracking-for-any-instance-of-the-context) [automatic change detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925111/turn-off-ef-change-tracking-for-any-instance-of-the-context)
2. [eagerly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading) loading the navigation collections
3. and potentially by directly manipulating [entry states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723276/delete-a-single-record-from-entity-framework/17723368).

or you could just go

### Not EF

[Get(more or less reliably) table name from its DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598857/dbset-table-name)(or just hardcode it if that's acceptable) and delete all the offending rows with plain SQL.

Basically use the right tool for the right job.

EF is usually a decent choice for modifying complex object graphs, but on the other hand it is basically too heavy-weight for bulk record manipulations.