# EF6 setting AutoDetectChangesDisabled

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

How do you set AutoDetectChangesDisabled to false on your context with EF6?

I just upgraded from 4.3.1 where I used OnCreated to do this.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you post the method where you are initializing your context ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DbContext AutoDetectChangesEnabled set to false detecting changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes)

Comment: As I understood it, I should be using DataManagerDbConfiguration and this.SetDatabaseInitializer. Does this sound correct?

Comment: I ended up setting it up where I initialize the context