# New DbContext is not pulling updated data if database is modified manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

**Background**

I have a central database my MVC EF web app interacts with following best practices.  Here is the offending code:

```
// GET: HomePage
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return View(new CustomViewModel()
                {
                    ListOfStuff = db.TableOfStuff
                        .Where(x => x.Approved)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
                        .ToList()
                });
    }
}
```

I also modify the data in this database's table manually completely outside the web app.

I am not keeping an instance of the `DbContext` around any longer than is necessary to get the data I need.  A new one is constructed per-request.

**Problem**

The problem I am having is if I delete a row or modify any data from this table manually outside the web app, the data being served by the above code does not reflect these changes.

The only way to get these manual edits of the data to be picked up by the above code is to either restart the web app, or use the web app to make a modification to the database that calls `SaveChanges`.

**Log Results**

After logging the query being executed and doing some manual tests there is nothing wrong with the query being generated that would make it return bad data.

However, in logging I saw a confusing line in the query completion times. The first query on app start-up:

```
-- Completed in 86 ms with result: CachingReader
```

Then any subsequent queries had the following completion time:

```
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: CachingReader
```

What is this `CachingReader` and how do I disable this?

Comment: Are you keeping a single instance of your context alive?

Comment: @Juan , no.  I am following best practices keeping the DbContext around only long enough to pull the data I need then disposing of it.  The `using` statement I thought would explain this.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes

Comment: Where exactly in your application are you instantiating the DbContext?

Comment: A new DbContext with a new DbConnection will always read from the database.  Try to create a simple, self-contained repro, and you'll probably find your issue.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  please read my edited post. I've posted the entirety of the offending code plus some more strange details.

Comment: That code will definitely query a database.  Try using a hard-coded connection string in the DbContext constructor to ensure you're hitting the right databases.  Or use Profiler or EF tracing to see the details of the database interaction.

Comment: I suspect a cache issue - do you have output cache for this view? is there a chance you are calling this view on ajax?

Comment: @ZivWeissman no output cache on the view.  The code is ran every time on page refresh, it's just the data in the table in the `DbContext` fetching cached/old data.  I've verified this by deleting rows in the table and still seeing them persist on page refresh and in counting rows in the table in the `DbContext`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have updated the original post with results of the EF tracing logs.  There appears to be caching going on, something about `CachingReader`.

Comment: Um, what EF Provider are you using.  Perhaps something like https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think you're on to something here.  I also have an MVCForum installation running on the same EF app and it's making use of that exact library.  I'll look into this further and post a solution if found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Culprit**

I discovered the error was introduced elsewhere in my web app as something that replaced the underlying `DbProviderServices` to provide caching, more specifically I am using [MVCForum](http://www.mvcforum.com/) which uses [EF Cache](https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache).

This forum's `CachingConfiguration` uses the default `CachingPolicy` which caches everything unless otherwise interacted with through the EF which was the exact behavior I was observing.  [More Info](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/)

**Solution**

I provided my own custom `CachingPolicy` that does not allow caching on entities where this behavior is undesirable.

```
public class CustomCachingPolicy : CachingPolicy
{
    protected override bool CanBeCached(ReadOnlyCollection<EntitySetBase> affectedEntitySets, string sql, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters)
    {
        foreach (var entitySet in affectedEntitySets)
        {
            var table = entitySet.Name.ToLower();

            if (table.StartsWith("si_") ||
                table.StartsWith("dft_") ||
                table.StartsWith("tt_"))
                return false;
        }

        return base.CanBeCached(affectedEntitySets, sql, parameters);
    }
}
```

With this in place, the database logging now always shows:

```
-- Completed in 86 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Thanks everyone!