# EF6 equivalent of EF Core's QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am searching for a way to globally disable change tracking in my `Context` class. This will prevent developers from forgetting to put `.AsNoTracking()` on each repository query as we currently do. This will also prevent us from manually having to `.Detach()` entities on occasion. I have found a solution in EF Core which is to do something like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

  public MyContext() { 
    ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = 
       QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
  }

  public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities {get;set;}
}
```

However, the `Context` class in Entity Framework 6 does not appear to have a `QueryTrackingBehavior` property on it's `ChangeTracker`. Is there a way to accomplish this using Entity Framework 6?

Please note that I have already looked into using `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` and it does not work for the reasons outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes).

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no similar functionality in EF6