# update multiple record at a time - EF + repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

My Code -

```cs
public void SaveTagOrder(List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> result) {
        foreach(var item in result){
      var entity = _vpsdbContext.Tags.FirstOrDefault(e => e.TagId == item.Key);
            if (entity != null) { entity.SortOrder = item.Value; }
        }
        _vpsdbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I just want to update multiple records at a time. as per my knowledge, I write this code but its added one by one. pls, tell me any another way to update multiple records at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there is no problem. EntityFramework Update works like this..

You can make some changes to speed up the process

**Option 1**

set **AutoDetectChangesEnabled**  to **False**  [Please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863382/dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled-set-to-false-detecting-changes)

```
 db.Tags
       .Where(x=>result.Contains(x.tagId))
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(a=>a.SortOrder = value);

 db.SaveChanges();
```

**Option 2**

you can try **EntityFramework** plug-ins for bulk operations it [here](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities)

**Here is a small extract from the performance section later in the document.**

```
Batch iteration with 25000 entities
Insert entities: 880ms
Update all entities with a: 189ms
Bulk update all with a random read: 153ms
delete all entities with a: 17ms
delete all entities: 282ms

Standard iteration with 25000 entities
Insert entities: 8599ms
Update all entities with a: 360ms
Update all with a random read: 5779ms
delete all entities with a: 254ms
delete all entities: 5634ms
```